# Transpose timestamps to start & end timestamp columns

Tags: sql, oracle, time-series

I have a series of timestamped records that give the count of people in locations. These are not at regular intervals, the count is given each time a change is detected. For example :

```
    TIMESTAMP         LOCATION       OCCUPANTS  
 ---------------- ----------------- ----------- 
  1602476920649    SOL2-5-MARS               4  
  1602476840140    SOL2-5-NEPTUNE           10  
  1602476821435    SOL2-4-SATURN             1  
  1602476709256    SOL2-4-SATURN             0  
  1602476505331    SOL2-5-NEPTUNE            8  
  1602476508223    SOL2-5-MARS               5  
  1602476438886    SOL2-4-JUPITER            4
```

I would like to transpose this to records that have a start and end timestamp for each location and count of people like the following. The last end timestamp would be the current timestamp that the query was run. This must be using Oracle SQL.

```
     LOCATION         START_TS          END_TS        OCCUPANTS  
 ----------------- ---------------- ---------------- ----------- 
  SOL2-4-SATURN     1602476821435    1602476821435            0  
  SOL2-4-SATURN     1602476821435    1602477395000            1  
  SOL2-5-MARS       1602476508223    1602476920649            5  
  SOL2-5-MARS       1602476920649    1602477395000            4  
  SOL2-5-NEPTUNE    1602476505331    1602476840140            8  
  SOL2-5-NEPTUNE    1602476840140    1602477395000           10  
  SOL2-4-JUPITER    1602476753698    1602476753698            4  
  SOL2-4-JUPITER    1602476753698    1602477395000            4
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `LEAD`. With `LEAD` you can read values of following rows. When there is no following row, you get `NULL`. Use `COALESCE` for the last rows per location hence.

```
select
  location,
  timestamp as start_ts,
  coalesce(
    lead(timestamp) over (partition by location order by timestamp),
    systimestamp) as end_ts,
  occupants
from mytable
order by location, timestamp;
```

(This query uses proper timestamps. Your sample data shows numbers instead. If you are storing numbers instead of timestamps, you'll have to convert `SYSTIMESTAMP` in above query to such number.)

Comment: Thanks Thorsten, this works nicely :) my timestamps are miliseconds since epoch so I am converting like this :

select
  location,
  timestamp,
  CAST(DATE '1970-01-01' + (1/24/60/60/1000) * timestamp AS TIMESTAMP) as start_ts,
  coalesce(
    lead(CAST(DATE '1970-01-01' + (1/24/60/60/1000) * timestamp AS TIMESTAMP)) over (partition by device_name order by CAST(DATE '1970-01-01' + (1/24/60/60/1000) * timestamp AS TIMESTAMP)),
    CAST(SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(systimestamp) AS TIMESTAMP)) as end_ts,
  occupants
from mytable
order by location, timestamp;